# Evaluate the Determinants A?

Tags: linear-algebra

Evaluate the  Determinants

> $$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
>   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
>   -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
>   0 & -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\
>   0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
>   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
> \end{matrix}\right)$$

My attempst :    I  was  thinking abouts the 
Schur complement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

$\det \begin{pmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{pmatrix}= \det (A-BD^{-1}C)\det D
$

As i  not getting  How  to applied  this  formula  and finding the Determinant of the Given question,,

Pliz help me  or is  There another  way  to find  the  determinant of the matrix.

Thanks u

Comment: Notice that the sum of almost each column is the same. This can help you simplify your calculations (try adding all rows to the first row, for instance)

Comment: Using the formula you propose is not likely to make the calculation simpler here (interesting and useful as it may be). So you can use cofactor method or row reduce the matrix furst (here you need to keep track of how each tow operation affects the determinant.

Comment: @stupid The answer is not $6$, it is $8$. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$

To find the determinant you need to find the upper triangular matrix and then multiply the diagonal elements of the matrix.

$$=\begin{vmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}_{R_2->R_2+R_1}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}_{R_3->R_3+\dfrac12R_1}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0& \dfrac32 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}_{R_4->R_4+\dfrac23R_3}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0& \dfrac32 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & 0 & \dfrac53 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{vmatrix}_{R_5->R_5+\dfrac35R_4}$$
$$=\begin{vmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0& \dfrac32 & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & 0 & \dfrac53 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac85\\
\end{vmatrix}_{R_5->R_5+\dfrac35R_4}$$

Now the determinant $=1\times 2\times \dfrac32\times \dfrac53 \times \dfrac85=8$

Comment: But  i got  6 from jose carlos  answer,,,which  one  is correct 8 or 6?

Comment: $8$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the first line to the second one, your matrix becomes$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\  0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  0 & -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\  0& 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$and therefore$$\det A=\begin{vmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}1 & \frac12 & 0 & 0\\ -1& 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{vmatrix}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: no,, @ jose carlos sir  ..pliz  elaborate its

Comment: @stupid The next step is to add the first line to the second one and then to do a Lapalce expansion along the first column. That will lead you to the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix and so on.

Comment: @stupid I think that I have already elaborated enough.

Comment: You can do cofactor expansion without the first step - you will have 'two terms' instead of one term in J Santos' answer

Comment: @stupid The answer is a mixture of 'row reduction'  (to simplify the matrix, get an extra zero in the clmn we expand along) and then cofactor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix with dimension $n=5$:
$$T_n=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\\
c  & a & b & 0 &  0 &  0\\
0 & c & a & b & 0 & 0  \\[-1ex]
& &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\[-1ex]
&&&\ddots& a& b \\
0 & 0  & 0 & & c & a
\end{pmatrix}$$

You can try to prove the recurrence formula
$$\det T_n =a\det T_{n-1}-bc\,\det T_{n-2},$$
which here yields $$\det T_n =\det T_{n-1}+\det T_{n-2}.$$

Comment: $det T_5 = det T_4  + det T_3  = 5 +4  = 9$   is its corrects ??? @Bernard

Comment: @stupid: Not exactly,as $\det T_3=3$. (b.t.w. the code for det is`\det`). Check: $\det T_1=1$, $\det T_2=2$, so $\det T_3=2+1$. You also can get it with a direct calculation, by *Sarrus' rule*.

Answer (score 1):

To do your method, you'd need to  'divide' your matrix into 4 submatrices (sections of your matrix) $A,B,C,D $. You then need to check and see if $D $ is invertible fir this to work.